# Installing SQL Server 2014 express on Windows server 2012 box

Tags: sql-server

While Installing SQL Server 2014 express on a new Windows server 2012 box, we are having problems with SQL Server Database Engine Service - the request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. 
After the install if you try to restart the Database Engine Service - it gives the same error and fails. It's happening on the local server. Using the same management studio I am able to access other DB's in the network.

Comment: Would be good if you can get some details from the setup error log file.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the account being used by the service.  Have you tried another account, maybe local admin just to see?  You can view and change the account using the configuration manager.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Tried that option too but it didn't work - both the account's SQL db service are failing to start. Is anyone aware of the list of services that are disabled in windows server 2012 by default which needs to be enabled. Someone mentioned that could be the problem - which could help us out here. Looking at the dump - it points out to be SQLOS.DLL issue.

Comment: Have you tried to repair the install?  I usually install standard edition but I have never had an issue with any version of windows server.  The sql setup would take care of everything.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I tried that option - this failure still remains

Comment: You will need to look into your event logs corresponding to when you try to start the service.

Comment: The error log says Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2014.120.2000.8, Faulting module name: SQLOS.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18194, Exception code: 0xc0000142 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe